# Hide images from DataGridViewImageColumn

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, datagridview

I need to hide or show images for individual cells in a DataGridViewImageColumn. I put the code in cell formatting event. But I have no idea how to hide images from cells. The only way I know how to remove images would be first set the image column's Image property to null and then set each cell's image to some images for display. But this is a bit inconvenient because the image show/hide code is now in my cell formatting event.

Anyone knows easy way to hide/remove images from individual cells? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I was just searching for the solution to the same problem and the one I've settled for the following:

```
if (showImage == true)
{
    imageCell.Value = new Bitmap(iconPath);
}
else
{
    imageCell.Value = new Bitmap(1, 1);
}
```

If the background of your cell is white the 1x1 bitmap won't be visible. Otherwise you'll have to color that pixel according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks friend, I was looking for more than an hour the solution. If I could I would give you a hug.

Comment: I have tried it with a DataGridView with alternate colours white - grey and I'm sure that pixel is not visible, even with Zoom 500%, so that's cool, +rep